# SMSAccount Class on Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile, outlook, sms, account

I'm writing an application for a Windows Mobile phone in VB.Net, and I would like to read SMSs from the phone's memory. According to MSDN, the SMSAccount class is what I need:

```
'SmsAccount Class
'Provides access to a Outlook Mobile Short Message Service (SMS) account, the account's SMS folders, and the SMS messages they contain.
```

However, the SMSAccount Class only has one interesting method, aka `Send` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.smsaccount_members.aspx), and I can't figure out how to access the actual messages.

I've found examples on the web which suggest to use the smsAccount.Inbox property, which I can't manage to find. I got this code for example :

```
Dim smsAcc As SmsAccount
Dim smsFdr As SmsMessageFolder
smsFdr = smsAcc.Inbox
```

But I cant find either of the SmsMessageFolder class and the Inbox property.

How do I access smss?

Thanks for your help,
CFP.

Comment: Do you want to access existing messages or only when there is a new message coming?

Comment: I'd like to access existing messages (for backup purposes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link...

[Getting SMS Messages from Pocket Outlook in Windows Mobile 5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxcompact/thread/c1b3b906-e027-4439-a528-54d7cb47b8fe)

It seems to suggest there is no easy way to do it. I noticed when I did a search for this that [this company](http://inthehand.com/content/Mobile.aspx) do a third party implementation. I don't know much about them except it seems to be the suggested answer on several forums (so you may already know about it).

Comment: Yup, thanks, I knew about that one. But it's strange that the doc is not in line with actual features...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go native or write your own wrapper for some native implementations [(1)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/f4bfc9bb-818b-4016-a52b-5f239ed1b0e4) [(2)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/60045e0b-2d5b-419d-a3ff-9ee1ec5e867c/)

Comment: Yup, but this would take much too long ; I was hoping that the documented classes would actually exist...